# Is there a difference between "with time" and "over time"?

Tags: prepositions

Student's vocabulary knowledge is a building process which occurs ______ (with time/over time). Which one is correct here? Or the both is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, the sentence is ungrammatical. Secondly, it's awkwardly phrased from start to finish. Where did the article *a* that should be in front of *student* go? Knowledge of any kind is not a process. It's also not at all clear what you're trying to say with the phrase *a building process*. It sounds like a process that has to do more with construction engineering or architectural design rather than with leaning new words. You would use the verb *to occur* to describe things that you can't control. Building your vocabulary, however, is a process that's completely under your control. So, I don't think *occurs* is going to work there.

I were you, I'd just rewrite this sentence entirely:

> Building one's vocabulary is a process that takes time.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment. I found it in a book and just copied that. But my real concern is "with time vs over time" whatever the other parts of the sentence are.

Comment: I'd say **occur with time** and **occur over time** are both fine (though, **occur over time** is probably more common). Which sounds better will depend on the context.