# change with time vs change over time

Tags: difference

I wrote this sentence:

> The probability distribution changes with time.

Then, someone edited the sentence for 'changes over time' instead of 'changes with time'.

What is the difference between the two phrases?

I found [a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/161187/116378) but it doesn't have a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Changes with time” implies a direct correlation between time and the change. If you travel at a constant velocity, your position changes with time. If you accelerate at a constant rate, your velocity changes with time. If there is not a direct link between time and the change, the change is occurring **over** time.